# What is the size of the actual image?

Tags: docker

I have the following images:

```
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
softshipper/foo-service   latest              f3bcb2966414        5 seconds ago       295MB
openjdk                   11.0.5-jre          499aaf14790b        4 weeks ago         267MB
```

is the real size of the `softshipper/foo-service` 28MB(295 - 267) or 295MB?

The docker file looks as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.5-jre as stage0
LABEL snp-multi-stage="intermediate"
LABEL snp-multi-stage-id="7dad9ef8-0561-42df-950d-e186b93ff4b0"
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY opt /opt
USER root
RUN ["chmod", "-R", "u=rX,g=rX", "/opt/docker"]
RUN ["chmod", "u+x,g+x", "/opt/docker/bin/foo-service"]

FROM openjdk:11.0.5-jre
USER root
RUN id -u demiourgos728 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || (( getent group 0 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || ( type groupadd 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && groupadd -g 0 root || addgroup -g 0 -S root )) && ( type useradd 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && useradd --system --create-home --uid 1001 --gid 0 demiourgos728 || adduser -S -u 1001 -G root demiourgos728 ))
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY --from=stage0 --chown=demiourgos728:root /opt/docker /opt/docker
USER 1001:0
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/foo-service"]
CMD []
```

Comment: What do you mean by "real size"?  If you push the image to a registry, and pull it on to a clean system, it will require the full 295 MB; if you happen to have that specific JRE image anyways, it will only require the smaller amount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real size of `softshipper/foo-service` is 295MB. However, `softshipper/foo-service` is based on `openjdk`, which means `softshipper/foo-service` uses some layers of `openjdk`.

Thus, the real size of `softshipper/foo-service` is 295MB, and the real size of `openjdk` is 267MB. However, the real size of `softshipper/foo-service` + `openjdk` is less than 295+267MB, since the two images use some same layers.

Notice that the real size of `softshipper/foo-service` + `openjdk` cannot be known by simple plus or minus. The size depends on the same layers they both use.